# SAS importing multiple datasets to save name of dataset as variable

Tags: sas, dataset

I need to access a directory with some sas datasets named all_ci, all_pd, all_vs, etc.  ci would be 'care info', pd would be 'patient data' and vs would be 'vital stats.'  I am reading them in as such:

```
data ci_all;
set DIRECTORY.all:; run;
```

I get a table that looks like this:

```
No.  
16
25
20
```

This works in only setting all the sets that begin with all.  The issue is that I need an output that looks like this:

```
Category          No.
Patient Data      16
Vital Statistics  25
Care Info         20
```

Since the original all_ datasets do not have the category label, I have to manually count in which order the all_ dataset was read, and then label it.  I was wondering if there was a way which saves the name of the dataset that's being read in so I can easier label them in the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the INDSNAME option on the SET statement.  You need to copy the value to a new variable since the variable referenced in the dataset option is automatically dropped.

```
libname DIRECT 'mydirectory' ;
data ci_all;
  lenght dsname indsname $41 ;
  set DIRECT.all: indsname=indsname;
  dsname=indsname;
run;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this saves me a lot of time.

Comment: Might want to note version it's applicable for (9.3+).